# Can I create an algebra on a set of numbers defined as $A=a-a$ with equivalence relation $A=B \Leftrightarrow a=b$

Tags: abstract-algebra

It seems to be a valid idea. In the field of real numbers it is assumed that for any $a, b \in R$

$$
a-a=b-b=0
$$

But what if we redefine the equivalence relation in such a way that

$$
a-a = b-b \Leftrightarrow a=b
$$

And the ordering of elements:
$$
a-a > b-b \Leftrightarrow a>b
$$

If we restric ourselves to positive numbers $a,b>0$ we can easily define both addition and multiplication:

$$
(a-a)+(b-b)=(a+b)-(a+b) \\
(a-a)*(b-b)=ab-ab+ab-ab=2ab-2ab
$$

We can also define the multiplicative identity:

$$
(a-a)*(u-u)=(a-a) \\
2au=a \\
u=\frac{1}{2}
$$

And the multiplicative inverse:

$$
(a-a)*(b-b)=(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}) \\
2ab=\frac{1}{2} \\
b=\frac{1}{4a}
$$

So I think it seems to be a group, namely a commutative semiring without additive identity. I don't know the abstract algebra though.

Is there any reason why I can't create an algebra this way?

Comment: There is some problem in the steps for defining the multiplicative identity...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you pull rigor into your equations (since your equations read alot of $0=0$), you end up with
$$T_a + T_b = T_{a+b}\\
T_a \cdot T_b = T_{2ab}$$
Where $T_a$ is the element of your "new" ring and $a$ is an element of $\mathbb R$.

Now your "new" ring $(X, \cdot, +)$ with elements and operations as defined above has
$$T_a + T_0 = T_a\\
T_a \cdot T_{\frac12} = T_a\\
T_a + T_{-a} = T_0\\
T_a \cdot T_{\frac1{4a}} = T_{\frac12}$$

In other words, the multiplicative identity is $T_{\frac12}$ and the additive identity is $T_0$.

Comment: Thanks, but do you think it's valid to use 0-0 as an element in this case?

Comment: @YuriyS You should get off that "$a-a$" thing. It's completely bogus. If you really did that rigorously, you end up with the zero-group $\{0\}$.

Comment: well thanks for the warning, I get it